# How to know Android Phone is going to sleep?

Tags: android

How to know Android Phone is going to sleep?
Please Help me with a sample code.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to register a broadcastreceiver for Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

So, create the broadcastreceiver

This is where you handle the screen_off intent.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    /*
     * dispatch screen_off
         * to handler method
     */

    String iAction = intent.getAction();

    if (iAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
    handleScreenAction(iAction);

}

};
```

Now the filter to register the receiver.

```
static void registerReciever() {
    IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter();
    // Catch screen off event
    myFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(receiver, myFilter);
}
```

Comment: Nothing is happening  
Can you provide the full code please It will be a great help

Comment: You'll need to declare the receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml too.

Comment: Incorrect.  This is one of the intents which cannot be declared for a receiver in the manifest.  In any case, you don't want to do both manifest and in code.